# Why can't you divide matrices with eachother?

Tags: linear-algebra

Recently I started learning about matrices and what you can do with them. I learned how to add them, subtract them and multiply them, but I found out that apparently you can't divide them. Why is this?

Comment: The reason I said "with eachother" in the title is because I am aware that you can divide a matrix by a scalar.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599121/why-cant-you-divide-matrices).

Comment: Division is the inverse of multiplication, i.e. $a/b=ab^{-1}$. Not all matrices are invertible.

Comment: There are zero divisors, which are non-zero matrices that when multiplied by each other will be the zero matrix. Zero divisors are never invertible, so you can't divide with them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the 2x2-matrix who's first column is [1,0] and whose second coumn is [0,0]. Suppose you could divide it, that would mean that there is a matrix $B$ such that $BA$ is the identity matrix $I$ (so $B=I/A$ in this sense).

That would mean that for any vector $v$, you would have $BAv=Iv=v$. If $v=(0,1)$, for example, you would have $v=BAv=B(Av)=B\vec{0}=\vec{0}$, since every matrix times the zero vector should be the zero vector. So you get that $v=(0,1)=(0,0)$, which is a contradiction.